# Is labeling a numerical quantity "high," as opposed to "large," metaphorical, conventional, or technical?

Tags: word-usage, metaphors

Why do we say "high frequency" and "high IQ" instead of "large frequency" or "large IQ"? Are these spatial metaphors? Are they just examples of language conventions with no technical or metaphorical connotations or implications? Is there some technical, logical, or mathematical reason for the use of "high" and "low" instead of "large" and "small" in these and certain other contexts?

Comment: Obviously labeling a number as ***high*** is metaphorical, since numbers are abstract concepts, whereas ***height, altitude*** is a real-world attribute. But metaphors are never "perfect". When associated with a "derivative" referent such as ***frequency*** (where the relevant *high / large **number*** relates to ***cycles per second***), there's scope for confusion because (metaphorically smaller) ***shortwave*** is ***high*** frequency, whereas ***longwave*** is ***low*** frequency (with a ***larger*** interval between cycles, and ***higher wavelength***)

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 One could say the same about 'large' and 'small': size is a real-world attribute which does not literally apply to numbers.

Comment: @JiK: [*All language is metaphor.*](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/778754-all-words-in-every-language-are-metaphors) I'm just making the point that almost all "metaphoric" usages break down at *some* point. In this context, metaphoric *scalar* values ("big/small numbers") clash with metaphoric *spatial, distance* values ("high/low frequencies") - especially when we consider ***wavelength*** as a relevant aspect of the attribute.

Comment: We do use metaphoric "size" as well as "height" for "intelligence" - through the "proxy" noun ***brain***, as in [***He's got a big brain.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+got+a+big+brain%22) Or for the opposite end of that particular spectrum, we can introduce yet *another* level of "metaphoric indirection" with [***He's a pea brain.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%27s+a+pea-brain%22)

Comment: Most of the things to which _high_ applies are things that are measured using instrumentation.  A _high temperature_ or a _high pressure_ will show their values at the _high end_ of a temperature or pressure gauge (which is traditionally, the top of the gauge).

Answer (score 9):

As outlined in [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/340283/11296), the use of high and low, or large and small, are conventions. There are however many situations where height and size are closely linked in such a way that if an object is big it is also high, so the link between the two conventions is understandable and natural.

Mathematicians use the wording "greater than" or "less than" to compare numbers, but there is nothing inherently better or worse about these words than the others.

High and low are more likely to be used where the numbers are imagined as being on a scale, so we refer to high values of temperature for example. Large and small are more likely to be used where the numbers are imagined as referring to sizes or amounts, so we refer to large values of weight. The understandings are close enough though, that we can easily understand a reference to "large temperature values" or to "high weight values".

Comment: "below" and "above" are also sometimes used in comparing abstract numbers, which fits with greater-valued positive numbers being "higher".  (e.g. in computer programming, when we need to distinguish a signed comparison from an unsigned interpretation of the same bits, assembly languages often use "above" or "higher" as the name of the unsigned integer condition, and "greater" as the name of the signed integer condition.)

Answer (score 2):

They are just conventions. They are sufficiently well established that using "small" or "large" instead of "low" and "high" would sound strange.

The same convention applies to temperature, energy, aptitude, performance, ...

Comment: High/low is more likely to be used where the numbers are imagined as being on a scale. Large/small is more likely to be used where the numbers are imagined as referring to sizes or amounts. Mathematicians use greater than and less than to compare numbers, but these words are just using the size metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers can measure many different kinds of things. Words we use to describe the number depend on the sort of thing we're counting or measuring.

If we're talking about size, we say "large" or "small". (Or "big", or various other words.)

If we're talking about longitude, we say "west" or "east".

If we're talking about distance, we say "near" and "far".

Etc.

I've never heard someone say, "This place has a very large longitude" or "The temperature here is very far".

"High" and "low" are general words used when more specific words aren't relevant. We don't have specific words to describe levels of intelligence, so we say "high" or "low" IQ. I suppose one could say "smart" or "dumb", but those are generally considered too informal and most words for low intelligence are at least somewhat insulting.

So yes, just what words we use with the number for any given "thing" is a matter of convention.